# Load datatable state with old timestamp

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to have links to specific pages of datatable, with sorting and etc. I did this by saving state in hash:

```
 window.DTapi = table.DataTable({
            "stateSave": true,
            "stateLoadCallback": function () {
                if (location.hash) {
                    return JSON.parse(location.hash.replace('#', ''));
                }
                return undefined;
            },
            "stateSaveCallback": function (oSettings, oData) {
                location.hash = JSON.stringify(oData);
            }, ...
```

If I load state older than 1 hour, datatable reinitialize.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this a proper way to save links to datatable pages?
2. How to handle my timestamp problem?